# Trouble Adding Corner Radius to ImageView Inside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitableview

I've created a custom UITableViewCell class where I've created a label and imageview, and connected them via storyboard. What's the best place to apply corner radius, border width, etc. to the imageView?

I tried the following in the custom class' init method but it didn't quite work:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    productImageView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor whiteColor]);
    productImageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    productImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 36.0f;
}
return self;
}
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you doing in this in the UITableViewCell subclass? If so you need add this in `awakeFromNib` or `prepareForReuse`. When init is called the image view doesn't exist yet.  Also do `self.productImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;`